# Cant get my JS function, which plays videos one at a time, to work on scroll to snap

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a container which allows for snap scroll to a background image so everything is framed well. I am trying to add videos instead of images to a page but need them to fire one at a time as the user goes down the page. It seems that the snapscroll function is not allowing my videos to autoplay. I'm not really sure what the problem is tbh...

The scroll snap code:

```
      const gra = function(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      }
      const init = function(){
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('bg-image');
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          items[i].style.background = randomColor({luminosity: 'light'});
        }
      }
```

The autoplay on scroll code:

```
      var videos = document.getElementsByClass("video"),
      fraction = 0.8;
      function checkScroll() {

          for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

              var video = videos[i];

              var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
                  b = y + h, //bottom
                  visibleX, visibleY, visible;

                  visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
                  visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

                  visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

                  if (visible > fraction) {
                      video.play();
                  } else {
                      video.pause();
                  }

          }

      }

      window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
      window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are video Autoplay policy changes in effect (since Jan 2019) that do not permit autoplay without a user gesture and thank God for that!

This is valid at least in Chromium browsers and I think Mozilla too.

You can override the policy with a command line parameter for yourself to test your code, but what good is that if it won’t work with others.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I was looking for something like this but wasnt able to find it until now. Should I use gifs instead of video? My videos dont have audio and when I change the video tag to include <video autoplay muted> it still doesnt work in firefox or chrome.?

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay will only work if you specify it as muted by default, like this.

```html
<video autoplay muted>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Don't worry, users will be able to unmute the video as part of the HTML5 video element.